# Is it haram to laugh at big chungus?

Tags: halal-haram, laughter

Salam alaikum, this question seems weird but listen to my story. Every day after coming back from school I look at an image of big chungus and laugh hysterically for around 15min, it's the only time of the day when I feel happy. One day my mother insisted on knowing why I was laughing, after she saw the picture of big chungs she immediately turned off my computer and told me that what I was doing was haram and she refused to explain why.

Comment: You are laughing at someone because of their looks (obesity). That is understandably something a parent would want to discourage, ridiculing people is bad manners and forbidden.

Comment: Big Changus is essentially is a creation of Allah, the screen you are watching on is a creation of Allah. Think about it this way.

Comment: Isn't it just an animated character meant for comic relief???

Comment: I can't blame you, I find big chungus hilarious myself

Answer (score 2):

It is just a character from a cartoon so it doesnt really mean anything. I think your mother thinks that you are laughing at someone or something fat and thinks your a fat shamer.